# c# Simple Wait Thread Queue (Wait when queue is full) to download Multiple files from Sharepoint

Tags: c#, multithreading, sharepoint, queue, download

I have written a simple program to concurrently download multiple files from Sharepoint using Threading. I used a Do While Loop to make sure the program will wait whenever the queue is full.

Please see my comments below in code. I am looking for a more efficient way for the program to wait whenever the queue is full. With the Do While loop my program has 70% cpu usage, by adding a Thread.Sleep(1000), it is reduced to 30% CPU usage, but I think there must be a more efficient way, while not hurting the performance of the queue? Thanks

```
// Main Program to dispatch Threads to download files from Sharepoint
bool addedtoDownloader;
                    do
                    {
                        addedtoDownloader = ThreadDownloader.addJob(conn, item.FileRef, LocalFolderPath);

                       // ===== by having the following 2 lines below reduce CPU usage
                            if (addedtoDownloader == false)
                            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000);
                       // ====== Is there a better way to do this? ================
                    }
                    while (addedtoDownloader == false);





class ThreadDownloader
{
    public const int MaxThread = 15;

    public static List<Thread> ThreadList = new List<Thread>();


    public static bool addJob(ClientContext conn, string SrcFileURL, string DestFolder)
    {
        RefreshThreadList();

        if (ThreadList.Count() < MaxThread)
        {

            Thread t = new Thread(() => Program.DownloadFile(conn, SrcFileURL, DestFolder));
            ThreadList.Add(t);
            t.Start();
            return true;
        }

        return false;


    }

    public static void RefreshThreadList()
    {
        List<Thread> aliveThreadList = new List<Thread>();

        foreach (var t in ThreadList)
        {
            if (t.IsAlive)
            {
                aliveThreadList.Add(t);
            }
        }

        ThreadList.Clear();
        ThreadList = aliveThreadList;
    }



}
```

Comment: Use a [`BlockingCollection`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312.aspx) - as its name implies, it's designed for this kind of thing.

Answer (score 0):

This seems a good use-case for **semaphores**:

```
private static SemaphoreSlim semaphore = new SemaphoreSlim(MaxThread);

public static void addJob(ClientContext conn, string SrcFileURL, string DestFolder)
{
    semaphore.Wait();

    RefreshThreadList();

    Thread t = new Thread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                Program.DownloadFile(conn, SrcFileURL, DestFolder);
            }
            finally
            {
                semaphore.Release();
            }
        });
    ThreadList.Add(t);
    t.Start();
}
```

Comment: Thanks Pragmateek, but what if I am using only .net 3.5?

Comment: also, in this case, I think we do not need the ThreadList anymore right?

Comment: If you're stuck with 3.5 simply use the good old Semaphore class. And yes I think you can get rid of the threads list. :)

Comment: Thanks! It works! I do not know much about the internal working of Semaphore, do you think this method is better than doing the Do While loop as I have used in the question? Was my version thread-safe?

I know it's a lot of questions, but thanks!

Comment: Using synchronization primitives like Semaphore is better and in general you should avoid "busy waiting" (i.e. looping until condition is true).

Comment: Your **ThreadDownloader** class is **not thread-safe**, but **the way you use it**, with only **one thread**, the main one, calling *addJob*, **is thread-safe**. But if *addJob* is called from more than one thread you'll be faced with races and you could have more threads than wanted. Let me know if you want me to elaborate on this. :)